# How to change "replyPhone" in sms-notifications

Tags: sms

I have SharePoint 2010, everything is ok and i want sms-notofications. It works, but sender is "SharePoint".
How to change sender name?
I know that  is responsible for sender name, but how I can change it within SharePoint?